# Does tempnam generate file with unique random string in a fixed length?

Tags: php

I've been playing around with the tempnam function and was wondering does it create a file with unique random string in a fixed length or just a unique random string?

Comment: The length is not guaranteed AFAIK. That might lead to collisions.

Comment: aha thought so, thanks!